# C# generics: failure of generic type inference means I cannot use anonymous type

Tags: generics, c#-3.0, type-inference

I have a class Exporter which has a generic method which accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` and creates an export document by enumerating its property values using reflection:

```
  public class Exporter
  {
    public string Export<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
      //Implementation omitted
    }
  }
```

Because of generic type inference, I can supply this with an anonymous collection type. Note the absence of the generic parameter in the method call below:

```
string fooString =
        new Exporter().Export(new List<Foo>()
                                {
                                  new Foo() {Name = "cats", NumberOfHams = 1},
                                  new Foo() {Name = "dogs", NumberOfHams = 8}
                                }
                       .Select(x => new { TwiceTheHams = x.NumberOfHams * 2 }));
```

We all love C#3. However, I would like to adapt this class so that I can enter more information about the columns in the export document, for example the width.

I have created a new method in the export class which looks like this:

```
public string Export<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IEnumerable<ColumnDetails<T>> columnDetails)
    {
      //Implementation omitted
    }
```

Ideally, the syntax would be like this, where `foos` is of type `IEnumerable<Foo>`:

```
fooString = new Exporter().Export(foos,
                                      new List<ColumnDetails<Foo>>
                                        {
                                          new ColumnDetails<Foo>(x => x.Name, 12),
                                          new ColumnDetails<Foo>(x => x.NumberOfHams, 4),
                                        });
```

However, when I call the new `Export()` overload as above, the generic type inference doesn't seem to be clever enough to infer that the generic parameter `T` for the `ColumnDetails<T>` should be the same as the generic parameter `T` for the `IEnumerable`. This means that I must specify `List<ColumnDetails<Foo>>` as the parameter, and therefore I cannot use this with anonymous collections.

I'm really new to generics and type inference. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Do I need to restructure the code somehow?

Edit: this is what I cannot do, because Visual Studio needs the generic parameter for ColumnDetails, which I don't have:

```
fooString = new Exporter().Export(foos.Select(x => new {TwiceTheHams = x.NumberOfHams * 2}),
                                          new List<ColumnDetails>
                                            {
                                              new ColumnDetails(x => x.TwiceTheHams, 12)
                                            });
```

Comment: I do not see any reason for generics in provided code.

Comment: When you talk about "anonymous collections" and "anonymous types" I don't think you *really* mean anonymous types - at least, you haven't shown any calls to `Export` using an anonymous type. It would really help if you could give a complete example where it's failing...

Comment: @Tomas: it means you can provide an IEnumerable of any object (for example a business entity) and export it in a kind of report. Or the output of a Linq query. I can't see a way of doing this without generics.

Comment: @Jon: the second code block calls the Export<T> method with collection of anonymous type (which is what I mean by anonymous collection). The IEnumerable supplied to it is projected to an anonymous type using the Select() method.

Comment: @David there are no anonymous types in your code sample.

Comment: @David: Ah, I'd misread the call to Select as being *after* the Export. It would be simpler to just show a plain collection of anonymous type values, e.g. `new[] { new { X="x" }, new { X="y" }`. Again, a complete example would be useful. (How are you creating the `List<ColumnDetails<T>>` when `T` is anonymous for example?)

Comment: @Davy8: There's one - the `Select` call in the second example. I agree it's not very obvious though.

Comment: Ah, I was confused because he mentioned "Ideally, the syntax would be like this" and in that example there are no anonymous types.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a real balls-up of explaining what I want. But Jon's question 'how are you creating teh List<ColumnDetails<T>> when T is anonymous' is precisely my question! Thank you Jon!

Comment: @David In cases like this, i make business entity interface constraint on generic type, thus omitting reflection.

Comment: Tomas - I'd love to see what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @David: Okay, in that case it's probably a matter of using inference again (within the method call) but it's hard to know how to do that without knowing anything about what ColumnDetails is meant to be.

Comment: I'm going to repost this question more clearly to see if anyone can make more sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

The `anonList` lets you have a reference `IEnumerable<anontype>` and the `T foo` in `CreateColumnDetails<T>` lets the compiler infer what type T is, allowing you to construct the object with an anonymous type as the value of `T`

```
class Program
{
    public static ColumnDetails<T> CreateColumnDetails<T>(T foo, Func<T, object> func, int x)
    {
        return new ColumnDetails<T>(func, x);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
        var anonList = foos.Select(x => new {TwiceTheHams = x.NumberOfHams*2});
        var fooString = new Exporter().Export(anonList,
                                      anonList.Select(y => CreateColumnDetails(y, z => z.TwiceTheHams, 12)));
    }
}
public class Exporter
{
    public string Export<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IEnumerable<ColumnDetails<T>> columnDetails)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public class ColumnDetails<T>
{
    public ColumnDetails(Func<T, object> func, int x)
    {

    }
}
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfHams { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've explained this poorly. What I mean is I can't call `Export<T>(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<ColumnDetails<T>> y)` if `x` is a collection of an anonymous type, because then I can't instantiate the collection of `ColumnDetails<T>`. God, this is hefty stuff.

Comment: @David Can you show what ColumnDetails looks like?  That might help.

Comment: This works, but as you say it's a little ugly. I think basically my original thought was correct - generic type inference just doesn't go this far.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be sufficient to fix it?

**Export<Foo>**

```
fooString = new Exporter().Export<Foo>(foos,
     new List<ColumnDetails<Foo>>
          {
               new ColumnDetails<Foo>(x => x.Name, 12),
               new ColumnDetails<Foo>(x => x.NumberOfHams, 4),
          });
```

Comment: The code works at present with known types such as Foo. It doesn't work with collections of anonymous types.

Comment: I see. Anonymous types might be tougher because you must use inference. You can always switch to Export<dynamic> and let it fly without a safety net.

Comment: @Micheal it's doable without `dynamic` even though it's a little ugly.  See the latest edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to pass in a `List<ColumnDetails< *anonymouse type with TwiceTheHams property* >>` ?

It looks to me like you need a generic helper function that will take an `IEnumerable<T>` parameter and construct a list of `ColumnDetails` objects from it. Then insert a call to that function as the second parameter to `Export`.