# Can't use generics to improve API because of limitation of generic type inference

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-inference

I have a class which is designed to take a collection of any type of object and create an export (e.g. Excel spreadsheet) of it. I can supply column names and widths as I choose:

Here is a summary of the class:

```
public class ObjectExporter
{
    public string Export<T>(IEnumerable<T> objects, IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition> columnDefinitions)
    {
      //Iterate through list of ColumnDefinitions.
      //Output value of the property in each object...
      //...whose name is equal to the PropertyName of the current ColumnDefinition
    }
}
```

Here is the ColumnDefinition class:

```
public class ColumnDefinition  {
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public ColumnDefinition(string columnName, string propertyName, int width)
    {
      ColumnName = columnName;
      PropertyName = propertyName;
      Width = width;
    }
  }
```

And here's an example of usage:

```
private void TestObjectExporter()
{
      ObjectExporter objectExporter = new ObjectExporter();
      //Note that the following variable changeRequests is a collection of anonymous type
      var changeRequests = ChangeRequestRepository.All.Take(5).Select(x => new { x.ChangeRequested, x.DateCreated, x.CreatedBy.Username });
      Response.Write(objectExporter.Export(changeRequests, new List<ColumnDefinition>()
                                              {
                                                new ColumnDefinition("Change Requested", "ChangeRequested", 12),
                                                new ColumnDefinition("Date Created", "DateCreated", 12),
                                                new ColumnDefinition("Created By", "Username", 12)
                                              }));
}
```

It is critical that ObjectExporter can work with collections of anonymous types. I would like to amend the ObjectExporter and ColumnDefinition classes to use strongly-typed syntax like the following (note how the property names are specified):

```
Response.Write(objectExporter.Export(changeRequests, new List<ColumnDefinition>()
                                              {
                                                new ColumnDefinition("Change Requested", x => x.ChangeRequested, 12),
                                                new ColumnDefinition("Date Created", x => x.DateCreated, 12),
                                                new ColumnDefinition("Created By", x => x.Username, 12)
                                              }));
```

I believe the way to do this would be to create a `ColumnDefinition<T>` class. However, I cannot find a way to get the compiler to infer that `T` being used in the `IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition<T>>` parameter is the same as is being used in the `IEnumerable<T>` parameter. This means that I cannot use the class with collections of anonymous types anymore because I cannot explicitly specify the generic type arguments.

Can anyone work out a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, this is a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157753/c-generics-failure-of-generic-type-inference-means-i-cannot-use-anonymous-type. I decided to repost because I had not explained my requirements well enough.

Comment: What did you try? Post your attempted code with `ColumnDefinition<T>`

Answer (score 0):

In your column definition class, you would do something like this:

```
public class ColumnDefinition<T>
{
     public ColumnDefinition(string displayName, Expression<Func<T, string>> propertyExpression, int width)
     {
     }
}
```

Your object exporter signature would also change:

```
public string Export<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition<T>> columns)
{
}
```

Then, the type of T should be inferred from the enumerable being passed, and thus the second parameter would expect an IEnumerable>, which then means your ColumnDefinition class infers type T, and then the expression in the constructor picks up T.

EDIT: Alternatively:

Wrap your Enumerable into another class and then call methods on it.

```
public class ObjectWrapper<T> : IDisposable
{
     public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; protected set; }
     public IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition> Definitions { get; set; }     

     public ObjectWrapper(IEnumerable<T> source) 
     { 
         Items = source; 
         Definitions = new List<ColumnDefinition>(); 
     }

     public void AddColumnDefinition(string name, Expression<Func<T, string>> propertyExpression, int width)
     {
          /* Add Column Definition with Expression Data */
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind, but IntelliSense says 'Incorrect number of type parameters in reference to class ColumnDefinition<T>'.

Comment: After your update: how do I instantiate the `ObjectWrapper<T>` class with an anonymous type?

Comment: `new ObjectWrapper(myEnumerable)` should work, even with an unknown anonymous type enumerable.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the compiler can't do this kind of type inference at all: `var objectWrapper = new ObjectWrapper(changeRequests);`. It demands to know the type of `T`.

Comment: Maybe it's possible in VS2010? I'm using 2008.

Comment: Alternatively, you could do some reflection work and `MakeGenericType` on your ObjectWrapper to get the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a bit tricky without using a few hacks to force type inference. How about something like this?

```
Response.Write(objectExporter.Export(changeRequests, new[]
    {
        changeRequests.GetColumnDef("Change Requested", x => x.ChangeRequested, 12),
        changeRequests.GetColumnDef("Date Created", x => x.DateCreated, 12),
        changeRequests.GetColumnDef("Created By", x => x.Username, 12)
    }));

// ...

public class ColumnDefinition<T>
{
    public string ColumnName { get; private set; }
    public Func<T, object> Selector { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }

    public ColumnDefinition(string columnName, Func<T, object> selector, int width)
    {
        ColumnName = columnName;
        Selector = selector;
        Width = width;
    }
}

public static class ColumnDefinitionHelper
{
    public static ColumnDefinition<T> GetColumnDef<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
        string columnName, Func<T, object> selector, int width)
    {
        return new ColumnDefinition<T>(columnName, selector, width);
    }
}

public class ObjectExporter
{
    public string Export<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> objects, IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition<T>> columnDefinitions)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your change is not really generic, don't use generics.

If you can't substitute T with an Interface instance that is being implemented in T don't use generics. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Eh? If I COULD substitute T for an interface then I wouldn't need generics. In this case I do, because I might pass a collection of any type in. I don't understand what you mean at all.